# Can collections / iterables / streams be passed into @ParamterizedTests?

Tags: junit5

In Junit5 5.0.0 M4 I could do this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("generateCollections")
void testCollections(Collection<Object> collection) {
  assertOnCollection(collection);
}

private static Iterator<Collection<Object>> generateCollections() {
  Random generator = new Random();

  // We'll run as many tests as possible in 500 milliseconds.
  final Instant endTime = Instant.now().plusNanos(500000000);
  return new Iterator<Collection<Object>>() {
    @Override public boolean hasNext() {
      return Instant.now().isBefore(endTime);
    }

    @Override public Collection<Object> next() {
      // Dummy code
      return Arrays.asList("this", "that", Instant.now());
    }
  };
}
```

Or any number of other things that ended up with collections of one type or another being passed into my `@ParameterizedTest`. This no longer works: I now get the error

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException:
  Error resolving parameter at index 0
```

I've been looking through the recent commits to SNAPSHOT and I there's a few changes in the area, but I can't see anything that definitely changes this.

Is this a deliberate change? I'd ask this on a JUnit5 developer channel but I can't find one. And it's not a bug per se: passing a collection is not a documented feature.

If this is a deliberate change, then this is a definite use-case for `@TestFactory`...

Comment: Looks like a regression to me. Please, file an issue over at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/872

The next snapshot build should fix the regression.

Comment: Sorry meant to get back to you yesterday. Confirmed, working now.